# How to remove and add on mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

```
    /* 1 */
{
  "Equipments" : [ 
        {
            "equipmentName" : "tero bau",
            "qty" : 2,
            "itemPrice" : 5.0
        }, 
        {
            "equipmentName" : "khaire",
            "qty" : 6,
            "itemPrice" : 1.5
        }, 
        {
            "equipmentName" : "haru",
            "qty" : 4,
            "itemPrice" : 20.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "Equipments" : [ 
        {
            "equipmentName" : "jatho",
            "qty" : 6,
            "itemPrice" : 6.0
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to remove "tero bau" object from 1 and add it to 2 inside the "Equipments" as another object. I tried $pull but it removes the object but had to manually add the object to 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

Let the document be

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1.0, 
    "Equipments" : [
        {
            "equipmentName" : "tero bau", 
            "qty" : 2.0, 
            "itemPrice" : 5.0
        }, 
        {
            "equipmentName" : "khaire", 
            "qty" : 6.0, 
            "itemPrice" : 1.5
        }, 
        {
            "equipmentName" : "haru", 
            "qty" : 4.0, 
            "itemPrice" : 20.0
        }
    ]
}
```

and data to be inserted

```
 let data = {
        "equipmentName": "jatho",
        "qty": 6,
        "itemPrice": 6.0
    }
```

Code will be

```
db1.bulkWrite(
        [{
            updateOne: {
                "filter": { _id: 1, 'Equipments.equipmentName': "tero bau" },
                update: {
                    "$pull": { 'Equipments': { equipmentName: "tero bau" } }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            'updateOne': {
                'filter': { _id: 1, },
                'update': { $push: { Equipments: data } }
            }
        }
        ],
        { ordered: false, upsert: true }
    );
```

output would be

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1.0, 
    "Equipments" : [
        {
            "equipmentName" : "khaire", 
            "qty" : 6.0, 
            "itemPrice" : 1.5
        }, 
        {
            "equipmentName" : "haru", 
            "qty" : 4.0, 
            "itemPrice" : 20.0
        }, 
        {
            "equipmentName" : "jatho", 
            "qty" : NumberInt(6), 
            "itemPrice" : NumberInt(6)
        }
    ]
}
```